# Accessible List Bullets

Tags: xsl-fo

I am creating an accessible PDF file using FOP-API with XSL templates and XML input.

I need to show nested lists but I only have one standard bullet shape (bullet - &#8226) which is read by all screen readers. Since I have nested lists, I need to show 2 or more bullet types (square/arrow) which should be accessible by screen readers as well. Any help?

I have another problem wrt to list labels. I want all bullet labels to be read as 'bullet' by the screen reader. (marking them s artifact is not an option as it has been required to make all labels to be readable as BULLET)

Can I achieve that in any manner? (except for adding bullets as image & adding alt-text to them)

What all possible values are possible for role attribute in **fo:list-item-label role=?**

Comment: All bullets no matter what character they are should be tagged as Artifacts.

Comment: but our client does not accept that. they want all labels to be read as BULLETS by screen readers

Comment: Then you need a product that allows you to mark alt-text for the second level, third level bullets.

Comment: Kevin, is there any such product available? And, there is nothing we can do about that (adding text/alt-text for bullet) in FOP-API? Can I achieve this using the attribute 'role' for fo:list-item-label? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I do not know FOP, you have to check their manual. RenderX is what I know and you can set rx:alt-description, rx:actual-text, and rx:abbreviation for content in accessible documents. These allow you in many ways to mark specific content to be read in a different way.